# Projection error while clipping NICFI satellite images using GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine

I'm trying to clip NICFI satellite images with a shapefile I customized but it has the following projection error

Here's my code:

**IMPORTS**

var nicfi: ImageCollection "Planet & NICFI Basemaps for Tropical Forest Monitoring - Tropical Asia"

var shapefile2: Table projects/ee-geospatial2/assets/Nickel_Only_WGS84

**CODE**

```
var shapefile = shapefile2; // Replace with the path to your shapefile

// Function to create a cloud mask based on a threshold
var createCloudMask = function(image) {

  // Define a cloud probability threshold (adjust as needed)
  var cloudProbabilityThreshold = 20; // Example threshold of 20%

  // Select the appropriate bands from the NICFI image for cloud detection
  var redBand = image.select('red'); // Adjust to the actual band names

  // Use an algorithm (e.g., NDVI) to detect clouds based on the chosen bands
  var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['N', 'R']); // Example NDVI calculation

  // Create a binary cloud mask where 1 indicates clouds and 0 indicates clear sky
  var cloudMask = ndvi.lt(cloudProbabilityThreshold);

  // Invert the mask to get 1 for clear sky and 0 for clouds
  cloudMask = cloudMask.not();

  // Apply the cloud mask to the image
  var cloudMasked = image.updateMask(cloudMask);

  return cloudMasked;
};

// Filter basemaps by date
var startDate = '2019-01-01';
var endDate = '2019-06-30';

var basemap = nicfi
  .filter(ee.Filter.date(startDate, endDate))
  .first();

// Apply the cloud masking function
var cloudMaskedBasemap = createCloudMask(basemap);

// Clip the cloud-masked image using the shapefile
var clippedImage = cloudMaskedBasemap.clip(shapefile);

// Add the clipped image as a visualization layer to the map
Map.addLayer(clippedImage, {
  bands: ['R', 'G', 'B'],
  min: 64,
  max: 5454,
  gamma: 1.8
}, 'Clipped Image');

// Export the clipped image to Google Drive
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: clippedImage,
  description: 'cloud_masked_image', // Specify a description for your exported image
  folder: 'NICFI 2019 Nickel Only', // Specify the Google Drive folder where you want to save the image
  scale: 30, // Adjust the scale to match your data's resolution
  maxPixels: 1e13 // Set the maximum number of pixels for the export
});
```

**ERROR**

```
ID: NSM3FGSMZPY3CIIEKWIDC2I2
Phase: Failed
Runtime: 1s (started 2023-09-05 10:09:39 +0800)
Attempted 1 time
Error: Image.clipToBoundsAndScale: Projection error when constructing output region: Can't transform (-180.0,-90.0) (Error code: 3)
```

Comment: Your table is not shared.  Also, you shouldn't clip with an entire collection; use clipToCollection.

Comment: @NoelGorelick thanks for the tip! would you have an idea how to include a cloud masking option in exporting NICFI satellite images?